# Como é que funciona a função pthread_cond_timedwait()?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

O objetivo desta função é mostrar as horas, esperar durante 2 segundos, e voltar a mostrar as horas para ter a certeza que passaram 2 segundos.
Não estou a usar sleeps, pois esta função é para me ajudar a entender como funciona a função pthread_cond_timedwait para a poder usar como método de sincronização.

```
//gcc -Wall -pthread timedwait.c -o  timedwait


#define _OPEN_THREADS                                                           
#include <pthread.h>                                                            
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
#include <time.h>                                                               
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {                                                                        
  pthread_cond_t cond;                                                          
  pthread_mutex_t mutex;                                                        
  time_t T;                                                                     
  struct timespec t;                                                            

  if (pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL) != 0) {                                    
    perror("pthread_cond_init() error");                                        
    exit(2);                                                                    
  }                                                                             


  time(&T);                                                                     
  t.tv_sec = T + 2;                                                             
  printf("starting timedwait at %s", ctime(&T));                                
  pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &mutex, &t);                                                                                               
  time(&T);                                                                     
  printf("timedwait over at %s", ctime(&T));                                  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assim funciona:

```
int main() {
  pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
  pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
  time_t T;
  struct timespec t;

  time(&T);
  t.tv_sec = T + 2;
  t.tv_nsec = 0;
  printf("starting timedwait at %s", ctime(&T));
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &mutex, &t);
  time(&T);
  printf("timedwait over at %s", ctime(&T));
}
```

Acho que o defeito principal da sua tentativa foi ter esquecido de lockar o mutex, que é condição essencial para o pthread_cond_timedwait() operar. (Ele também destrava o mutex.)

O pthread_cond_timedwait() funciona semelhante a um sleep(2) neste exemplo porque ele espera pela variável de condição cond *até* o prazo máximo especificado no terceiro parâmetro. Por ser um programa single-threaded, ninguém vai chamar pthread_cond_signal() e o resultado é que sempre vamos esperar 2 segundos, a variável de condição apenas satisfaz o chamador e não faz nada realmente.

Comment: Testei agora dando lock e unlock ao mutex e nao funcionou, correu o segundo print, sem esperar segundo nenhum.

Comment: Testei meu código no MacOS, será que no Linux precisa pegar o horário com clock_gettime() em vez de time()? Outra hora vou testar isso, seria uma diferença interessante de documentar.

Comment: Eu meti aqui a resolução que funciona com a ajuda no stackoverflow inglês, e o clock_gettime foi usado, secalhar foi disso.

Comment: Testei no Linux agora e nem a minha versão nem a sua estavam funcionando. O que resolveu, para as duas, foi compilar com -lpthread. Acho que no MacOS o pthread é implícito, mas no Linux não, e o Linux joga o comportamento de nunca esperar por condição quando é compilado sem pthread (assume que é single-threaded).

Answer (score 0):

Fui ajudado no stackoverflow ingles, mais informações:
[Stackoverflow Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59112776/how-does-the-pthread-cond-timedwait-works)

```
/ gcc -Wall -pthread timedwait.c -o  exe

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    struct timespec t;
    int result;

    result = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (result != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_mutex_lock: %s\n", strerror(result));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    result = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t);
    if (result == -1) {
        perror("clock_gettime");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Return-value check is non-essential here:
    printf("starting timedwait at %s", ctime(&t.tv_sec));

    t.tv_sec += 2;
    result = pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &mutex, &t);
    if (result != ETIMEDOUT) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(result));
    }

    result = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t);
    if (result == -1) {
        perror("clock_gettime");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Return-value check is non-essential here:
    printf("timedwait over at %s", ctime(&t.tv_sec));

    // Return-value check is non-essential here, because we'll just exit anyway:
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Comment: No Linux tem de compilar com -lpthread para funcionar, e isso também conserta a "minha" versão. Bem interessante este caso.